# How to keep indexed a Maniphest task after editing its title

Tags: phabricator, maniphest

After a new Maniphest task has been created, chances are that you may need to change the task title to a new one with different keywords. However, upon editing the title, the task cannot be found by its new keywords but only by the old ones.

After manually reindexing the database the edited tasks can be found again but further changes in title will fail again until a new reindexation is issued.

I suppose the normal behavior is that tasks should be found anytime searching by their title without reindexing the database. Should I expect a different behavior from Maniphest?

Phabricator Version:
phabricator cb033673b6eb3dc8330d2ddea0fd358eae3b939a (Nov 16 2018)

Comment: Do you have the phabricator daemons (phd) running?  Phabricator does a lot of work in the background, including keeping your search index up to date.

Comment: Yes, that was the cause. After some reboot one of the daemons was not on duty. Thank you! I reindexed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual culprit is your phabricator daemons (background workers) aren't running.

From the phabricator directory:

```
# Check the status of daemons:
./bin/phd status

# (re)start the daemons:
./bin/phd restart
```

See [Managing Daemons with PHD](https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabricator/article/managing_daemons/). You can also try looking at the daemon console which should be reachable at https://your.phabricator.url/daemon/, this will show the queue of jobs so you can see if jobs are failing for some reason.